# How to present a view controller as a part of a view?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to present a `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` in a view. Normally when using `UIViewController.present()` it would cover up the whole screen, but I want it to be just a part of the screen. How can I do that?

What I have:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let controller: UIReferenceLibraryViewController = UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: "word")
        self.present(controller, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can still use `present` and present a view controller that takes up the whole screen, as long as that view controller is transparent and has the view you want to display in it.

Comment: You can add it as a child view controller

Comment: As of IOS 15, use `UISheetPresentationController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Container View. There are lots of guides out there like https://naveenr.net/beginning-container-views-in-ios/